# Ruby includes returns false and nil

Tags: ruby, class

Can someone explain what the difference between false and nil this case is:

```
irb(main):008:0> Fixnum < Integer
=> true
irb(main):011:0> Integer < Fixnum
=> false
irb(main):012:0> String < Numeric
=> nil
```

I realize that "strings are not numbers"
and that "not all integers are fixnums"

My thinking is naive and boolean. Either something includes something or not, true or false. But there appears to be a third option, like, "you are kidding, right?" ;-)

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Hi there, just noticed you didn't accept my answer. Was I not clear enough? Do you need more clarification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Object#<` method seems to act like this, given the code `A < B`:

- If `A` is 'higher' in the inheritance chain (eg, `B.kind_of?( A ) == true`) then **`true`**.
- If `A` is 'lower' in the inheritance chain (eg, `A.kind_of?( B ) == true`) then **`false`**.
- If `A` and `B` have no relation, then **`nil`**.

So, in your example. `Integer` inherits from `Fixnum`, obviously that implies that `Fixnum` *doesn't* inherit from `Integer`. And of course `String` has nothing to do with `Numeric`.

Here's some ['documentation'](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/object_8c.html#a67) in the form of MRI source code :)